# Find the greatest common divisor of $r+1$ binomial coefficients

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, binomial-coefficients, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $n,r\in\mathbb{N},$ with $n≥r.$ Find $\gcd(S_0,S_1,\ldots,S_r),$ where $S_k={{n+k}\choose{r}}.$

I think the $\gcd$ is $1.$ To see this, suppose $d=\gcd(S_0,S_1,\ldots,S_r).$ Then, $d|S_{k+1}-S_{k}$ for all $0≤k≤r-1.$ But,

$$S_{k+1}-S_{k}={{n+k+1}\choose{r}}-{{n+k}\choose{r}}={{n+k}\choose{r-1}}.$$

So, $d$ must divide all $r$ of these terms as well. We may do the same thing again and get that $d$ divides ${{n+k}\choose{r-2}}$ for all $0≤k≤r-2.$ We keep doing this (we have to do this $r-1$ times to be precise) till we eventually get that $d$ divides ${{n+k}\choose{1}}$ for $0≤k≤r-(r-1).$ This means that $d$ divides $n$ and $n+1.$ This readily gives $d=1.$

Does this look good? More importantly, is the solution rigorous enough for, say, an interview for admission into a math program?

As an aside, interesting things happen when we consider $d'=\gcd(S_0,S_1,\ldots,S_{r-1}).$ Doing the same thing shows that $d'|n.$ Suppose $n$ is prime. Then, one can show that if $r=n,$ then $d'=1.$ If $r<n,$ then $d'=n.$ To see this, note that when $r=n,$ we have $S_0=1.$ This automatically gives $d'=1.$ If $r<n,$ then, in each $S_k,$ the $r!$ or $(n+k-r)!$ do not "cancel out" the $n.$ Since $r<n,$ the $r!$ term can't "cancel out" the $n.$ And, since $n-r≤n+k-r≤n-1,$ the $(n+k-r)!$ term is also too small to "cancel out" the $n.$ Hence, $n$ divides each $S_k.$

Comment: Sounds good, but you can just go to $\binom{n+k}{0}$ for $0\le k\le r-r=0$, i.e. $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an answer as a long comment.

Essentially, you show that $\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^{r-k}\binom{r}{k}\binom{n+k}{r}=1$, which also can be seen as follows:
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^{r-k}\binom{r}{k}\binom{n+k}{r}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^{r-k}\binom{r}{r-k}\binom{n+k}{n+k-r}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{r}(-1)^{r-k}\binom{r}{r-k}(-1)^{n+k-r}\binom{-r-1}{n+k-r}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{r-k}\binom{-r-1}{n+k-r}\\
&=(-1)^{n}\binom{-1}{n}=\binom{n+1-1}{1-1}=\binom{n}{0}=1.
\end{split}
$$